# VB.NET DataGridView Cell Editing

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Edited / re-written due to jmcilhinney's comment...

I have a project which uses several DGVs bound to an Access db. The form designer show 3 data sets for some reason, even though the solution explorer shows only one and all the tables are shown in that one data set's designer.

I can edit the first DGV but not another on the same form, the first is filled with the following...

```
Me.PingMonitorPLC_IPsTableAdapter.Fill (Me.PingMonitorDataSet.PingMonitorPLC_IPs)
```

And the other is filled with the following code...

```
Me.ActiveAlarmsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PingMonitorDataSet1.ActiveAlarms)
```

jmcilhinney's comment is that I must be doing something wrong, the form load event only runs the code listed above.

I dont know why I have 3 data sets listed on the form designer and I am too scared to go deleting things as I have lost an entire project before because I corrupted the designer by deleting controls etc.

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Add a `DataGridView` to your form, bind a `DataTable` to it and edit away.  If you are unable to edit then it's because of something that you are doing, not because of something that you haven't done.

Comment: Have you tryed setting the column property ReadOnly to false in the designer or in code?

Comment: @GabrielStancu yes i did check that becuase i Googled this issue and checked that property... HOWEVER... i just checked again and the columns were set to read-only....... issue is now resolved... Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that!